# Como debugar em um servidor externo

Tags: php, netbeans

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em  `PHP` pelo  `NetBeans` e salvando diretamente em um servidor externo (HostGator), cada vez que eu dou um Ctr+s na  `IDE` ele faz automaticamente o upload das modificações.

Minha dúvida é o seguinte, desta forma é possível debugar a aplicação? 
Estou tento bastante dificuldades no desenvolvimento por não ter essa opção, procurei tutoriais sobre o  `Xdebug`, mas a maioria precisa configurar pelo  `XAMP` ou  `AMP` e como o meu caso é um servidor externo não tem nada disso.

Comment: Só é possível debugar se voce puder alterar o *xdebug.ini* no HostGator